# What will application do if application is running in background and user switch off the device and again switch on the device.?

Tags: android, android-intent

Actually ,i am working on a livechat application its works fine.This application is tabbed based application.I am using C2DM and TabHost for this Application.I am facing a problem.

1.When the application is running in background and user switched off the device(App will be kill i think in that case).When user again switched on the device and click on app icon then application is being crashed.

2.When the application is running in background and user switched off the device(App will be kill i think in that case).When user again switched on the device and if gets any c2dm notification then click on notification icon application is being crashed.

3.The problem i saw when i switch on the device and click on app launcher icon and showing exception at 
this is logcat of my app
http://paste.org/50682

this is tabHOst Class

http://paste.org/50683

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store data in `Preferences` to store values and try it.
So Next time check that values is that file or not.

If yes the app running fine and if not then start app form Basic.